# Setting instance members before super() call finishes

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I've decided I need some sort of Cancelable promise so I've tried to write it by myself. However, I've got stuck on impossibility to set instance member before super() call finishes - and for extending Promise, it may be needed to set something before super().

So, my question is: Is there a simple way how to achieve this without re-writing whole Promise functionality?

```
export class CancelablePromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    private onCancel: () => void = () => {};

    public constructor(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void, oncancel: (handler: ()=>void)=>void) => void) {
        super( (res, rej) => {
            executor(res, rej, ( handler: () => void) => { this.onCancel = handler ; });
        });
    }

    public Cancel(): void {
        this.onCancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use local variables - either to collect the resolver functions:

```
constructor(executor) {
    let resolve, reject;
    super((res, rej) => { resolve = res; reject = rej; });
    try {
        executor(resolve, reject, handler => { this.onCancel = handler ; });
    } catch(e) {
        reject(e);
    }
}
```

or to store the handler before creating the property:

```
constructor(executor) {
    let onCancel; // = default handler
    super((resolve, reject) => {
        executor(resolve, reject, handler => { onCancel = handler; });
    });
    this.onCancel = onCancel;
}
```

Comment: I cannot. In Javascript, this works; but in Typescript it's raising TS2376: `A 'super' call must be the first statement`.

Comment: [That's a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8277) :-) Maybe you can try to declare the variable with `var` after the `super()` call?

Comment: Yeah, I found it a moment before your comment :) 
I'm not sure that declaring var after a super() call will create a closure. I'm going to solve this by implementing it in pure javascript, and creating `d.ts` file.

Comment: Yes, the variable is hoisted, so the closure is always created. If it wasn't, the assignment would throw an error in strict mode.